# I want to clear duplicate cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the duplicate contents instead of deleting the entire row. I tried delete row macros from stack overflow but I am not able to code correctly. where ever I find delete row I change that to clear contents. Below is my example. I am looking some for the vba code.

```
                           **Before**
```

44451   NEW YORK    MY NAME        123456789    216611  1/11/1989   1
44451   NEW YORK    MY NAME        123456789    216611  1/11/1989   1
44452   LONDON          YOUR NAME      987654321    216612  9/8/1938    1
44453   NEVADA          OTHERS NAME 654321      216613  3/18/2008   1
44453   NEVADA          OTHERS NAME 654321          216613  3/18/2008   1

```
                            **After**
```

44451   NEW YORK    MY NAME        123456789    216611  1/11/1989   1
                            216611          1
44452   LONDON          YOUR NAME      987654321    216612  9/8/1938    1
                            216612          1
44453   NEVADA          OTHERS NAME    654321           216613  3/18/2008   1

Comment: Can you explain a bit better?, why do you keep 216611 from the second row and don't keep the rest? why does it get combined with row 3? why do you repeat 216612 when it only appears once? why don't you repeat  216613? Give a better example of what you want cause the one you gave us is does different things deppending on the content plus you gave a poor explanation of the problem, also give us your code even if it doesn't work, don't expect people to do the code for you, if you want that hire a professional!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Sub sample()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @Yogi Did this solution worked for you ? If Yes please accept the answer.